# Setting a default value for an array

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

This is a theoretical question to understand what is going behind the scenes.

If I run this:

```
q=( 11 22 33 )
q="${q-()}"
declare -p q
```

it outputs the expected:

```
declare -a p=([0]="11" [1]="22" [2]="33")
```

But if I run:

```
q=( 11 22 33 )
q="${q[@]-()}"
declare -p q
```

then I get this:

```
declare -a p=([0]="11 22 33" [1]="22" [2]="33")
```

I understand which way is the correct one, but I cannot explain why the latter produces the result it does. Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning to `q`, when it already has its array attribute set, is equivalent to assigning to `q[0]`. That is, you would get the same result with

```
q[0]="${q[@]-()}"
```

In your first code, `${q-()}` also expands to `${q[0]-()}` for the same reason, and that value is assigned back to `q[0]`, resulting in an apparent no-op. (In every case, `${...-()}` is the same as `${...}`, since you aren't dealing with any unset variables.)

Comment: So, in the first case, I am assigning q[0] to q[0] right?

Comment: Exactly. I should add that to the answer.

Comment: Alright! So, this has the effect I thought it had, ie initialize q to an array if it is not set already, otherwise keep it the same (although just by setting q[0] to q[0]).
If I wanted to use another array inside the curly brackets to assign to q, how should I have written the assignment?

Comment: To answer my comment, if you assign a new array directly to `q` then it gets set to the new array, eg `q=(aa bb cc)` or `q=("{other_arr[@]}")`.